# How to load CSR matrix directly into boost compressed_matrix?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, ublas, boost-ublas

I want to transfer a matrix from application A (using matrix in LDU format) to application  B (using the boost ublas compressed_matrix, CSR format).

I have a function converting the LDU format to CSR format. The ldu2csr function provides me with the three arrays required to store the sparse matrix in CSR format (CSR format details can be found here: [space allocated by compressed_matrix in boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754871/space-allocated-by-compressed-matrix-in-boost/3754900)):
    ...
    values[idx] = matrix.upper()[i];
    cols[idx] = column;
    rows[row]++;

How can I load these arrays directly into the corresponding ones of a boost ublas compressed_matrix?

Comment: Is `boost::compressed_matrix` really CSR?